# Google login method doesn't show

Tags: pokemon-go

I just updated the Pokémon Go app and it asked me to log in. But there is no option for Google. The only option I get is trainer login aghh, please help!

Answer (score -1):

This is because when you started the game ,Your birthdate was to low to gave a Gmail account , try making it something in the 1990's and then the Gmail option will appear , hope you found this useful .

Comment: Chears mate that worked